# cannot convert from method group to ushort

Tags: c#

I want to create a dictionary in my factory class that maps `MessageId` with the `MessageCreate` function.

```
private Dictionary<ushort, MessageWithBody> messagesList = new Dictionary<ushort, MessageWithBody>()
        {
            {A1Message.getMessageId,  A1Message.CreateMessage},
            {A2Message.getMessageId,  A2Message.CreateMessage}, 

        };
```

The above decleration is giving an error that `cannot convert from method group to ushort`

Both `A1Message` and `A2Message` is derived from `MessageWithBody` class

Comment: How the field `getMessageId` is defined inside the class? is that of type `ushort`

Comment: What is `getMessageId`?

Answer (score 1):

Update to:

```
var messagesList = new Dictionary<ushort, MessageWithBody>()
{
    {(ushort)A1Message.getMessageId(),  A1Message.CreateMessage()},
    {(ushort)A2Message.getMessageId(),  A2Message.CreateMessage()},  
};
```

You need to make sure you are calling the methods.

Comment: how do I pass parameters to CreateMessage?

Comment: A1Message.CreateMessage(paramYouWantToPass). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx